# Floating point arithmetics - summation - JavaDoubleStream

Tags: java, floating-point, sum, numerical-methods

One of the first things we learn in floating point arithmetics is how rounding error plays a crucial role in double summation. Let's say we have an array of double `myArray` and we want to find the mean. What we could trivially do is:

```
double sum = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   sum += myArray[i];
}
double mean = (double) sum/myArray.length;
```

However, we would have rounding error. This error can be reduced using other summation algorithm such as the Kahan one (wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm).

I have recently discovered Java Streams (refer to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and in particular **DoubleStream** (see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html).

With the code:

```
double sum = DoubleStream.of(myArray).parallel().sum();
double average = (double) sum/myArray.length;
```

we can get the average of our array. Two advantages are remarkable in my opinion:

1. More concise code
2. Faster as it is parallelized

Of course we could also have done something like:

```
double average = DoubleStream.of(myArray).parallel().average();
```

but I wanted to stress the summation.

At this point I have a question (which API didn't answer): is this method `sum()` numerically stable? I have done some experiments and it appears to be working fine. However I am not sure is at least good as the Kahan algorithm. Any help really welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says it:

> Returns the sum of elements in this stream. Summation is a special
> case of a reduction. If floating-point summation were exact, this
> method would be equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  return reduce(0, Double::sum);
> ```
>
> However, since floating-point summation is not exact, the above code
> is not necessarily equivalent to the summation computation done by
> this method.

Have you considered using BigDecimal to perform exact results?

Comment: Here is my confusion: is  `reduce(, Double::sum)` returning exact summation? In my opinion that is not the case. So, the documentation may read as: `DoubleStream.sum()` performs the exact summation. But I may be wrong.

Comment: My interpretation is that it can not be guaranteed to be exact, because mathematically floating-point operations can not be exact. BigDecimal does decimal arithmetic so it is exact, though slower.

Comment: Re “mathematically floating-point operations can not be exact. BigDecimal does decimal arithmetic so it is exact”: Those are contradictory statements since `BigDecimal` is floating-point. Also, `BigDecimal` cannot be exact in all operations, such as dividing by three.

Comment: Double operations are floating point operations with fixed precision. Floating point is not the same as real numbers. Floating point representation errors can not be avoided, that is a fact: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation. BigDecimal in Java uses arbitrary precision, not floating point. You are correct that BigDecimal can not return 1 / 3 in an exact way, but you can control the precision and rounding mode of the operation with any number of digits with `divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)`.

Comment: @aled: Re “BigDecimal in Java uses arbitrary precision, not floating point”: The first part of that is true, `BigDecimal` uses arbitrary precision. The second part is false. Floating point means the point floats. `BigDecimal` uses an integer significand and an exponent. The exponent scales the value represented—it effectively moves the decimal point from the fixed position at the end of the integer significand to some other position. That is what “floating point” means. As a courtesy, please abide by the custom of using “@username” in responses, to notify the other party.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, so I implemented the Kahan variant of Klein, mentioned in the wikipedia article. And a Stream version of it.

The results are not convincing.

```
    double[] values = new double[10_000];
    Random random = new Random();
    Arrays.setAll(values, (i) -> Math.atan(random.nextDouble()*Math.PI*2) * 3E17);

    long t0 = System.nanoTime();
    double sum1 = DoubleStream.of(values).sum();
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    double sum2 = DoubleStream.of(values).parallel().sum();
    long t2 = System.nanoTime();
    double sum3 = kleinSum(values);
    long t3 = System.nanoTime();
    double sum4 = kleinSumAsStream(values);
    long t4 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf(
        "seq %f (%d ns)%npar %f (%d ns)%nkah %f (%d ns)%nstr %f (%d ns)%n",
            sum1, t1 - t0,
            sum2, t2 - t1,
            sum3, t3 - t2,
            sum4, t4 - t3);
```

An a non-stream version of modified Kahan:

```
public static double kleinSum(double[] input) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    double cs = 0.0;
    double ccs = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        double t = sum + input[i];
        double c = Math.abs(sum) >= Math.abs(input[i])
                ? (sum - t) + input[i]
                : (input[i] - t) + sum;
        sum = t;
        t = cs + c;
        double cc = Math.abs(cs) >= Math.abs(c)
                ? (cs - t) + c
                : (c - t) + cs;
        cs = t;
        ccs += cc;
    }
    return sum + cs + ccs;
}
```

A Stream version:

```
public static double kleinSumAsStream(double[] input) {
    double[] scc = DoubleStream.of(input)
            .boxed()
            .reduce(new double[3],
                    (sumCsCcs, x) -> {
                        double t = sumCsCcs[0] + x;
                        double c = Math.abs(sumCsCcs[0]) >= Math.abs(x)
                                ? (sumCsCcs[0] - t) + x
                                : (x - t) + sumCsCcs[0];
                        sumCsCcs[0] = t;
                        t = sumCsCcs[1] + c;
                        double cc = Math.abs(sumCsCcs[1]) >= Math.abs(c)
                                ? (sumCsCcs[1] - t) + c
                                : (c - t) + sumCsCcs[1];
                        sumCsCcs[1] = t;
                        sumCsCcs[2] += cc;
                        return sumCsCcs;
                    },
                    (scc1, scc2) -> new double[] {
                        scc2[0] + scc1[0],
                        scc2[1] + scc1[1],
                        scc2[2] + scc1[2]});
    return scc[0] + scc[1] + scc[2];
}
```

Mind that the times would only be evidence, when a microworkbench would have been used.
However one still sees the overhead of a DoubleStream:

```
sequential  3363280744568882000000,000000 (5083900 ns)
parallel    3363280744568882500000,000000 (4492600 ns)
klein       3363280744568882000000,000000 (1051600 ns)
kleinStream 3363280744568882000000,000000 (3277500 ns)
```

Unfortunately I did not correctly cause floating point errors, and its for me late.

Using a Stream instead of the kleinSum would need a reduction with at least 2 doubles (sum and correction), so a `double[2]` or in newer Java a **`Record(double sum, double cs, double ccs)`** value.

Comment: This is really interesting! I will try myself! Thanks!

Comment: I tried your implementation of Klein sum. It is giving strange results (I must admit only in a strange corner case). Image you have a jump array of the kind: `[100000000, 0.00000001, 100000000, 0.00000001, ...]` with length 100000000; the correct mean would be `5000000.000000005`. Your sequential Klein sum produces a result of `4.9999999999999994E14` which is off using a precision of `1E-16`. Doing the same test using `DoubleStream.sum()` yields however the correct result! Floating-point is really headache.

Comment: The wikipedia algorithm looked plausible enough. Now I'll remove it from my box of code snippets. If imight be a wrong compiler optimisation, but I would not bet on my code being correct..

Answer (score 1):

A far less magical auxiliary approach is to sort the input by magnitude.
`float` (used for readability reasons only, `double` has a precision limit too, used later) has a 24-bit mantissa (of which 23 bits are stored, and the 24th one is considered 1 for "normal" numbers), so if you have the number 2^24, you simply can't add 1 to it, the smallest increment it has is 2:

```
float f=1<<24;
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(f).intValue());
f++;
f++;
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(f).intValue());
f+=2;
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(f).intValue());
```

will display

> ```
> 16777216
> 16777216   <-- 16777216+1+1
> 16777218   <-- 16777216+2
> ```

while summing them in the other direction works

```
float f=0;
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(f).intValue());
f++;
f++;
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(f).intValue());
f+=2;
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(f).intValue());
f+=1<<24;
System.out.println(Float.valueOf(f).intValue());
```

produces

> ```
> 0
> 2
> 4
> 16777220   <-- 4+16777216
> ```

(of course the pair of `f++`s is intentional, 16777219 would not exist, just like 16777217 for the previous case. These are not incomprehensibly huge numbers, yet a simple line as `System.out.println((int)(float)16777219);` already prints 16777220).

The thing applies to `double` too, just there you have 53-bits precision.
Two things:

- the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum--) actually suggests this: `API Note: Elements sorted by increasing absolute magnitude tend to yield more accurate results`
- `sum()` internally ends in [`Collectors.sumWithCompensation()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/94318f9185757cc33d2b8d527d36be26ac6b7582/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#L527), which explicitly writes that it's an implementation of Kahan summation. (GitHub link is of JetBrains because Java uses different source control, which is a bit harder to find and link - but the file is present in your JDK too, inside src.zip, usually located in the `lib` folder)

Ordering by magnitude is something like ordering by log(abs(x)), which is a bit uglier in code, but possible:

```
double t[]= {Math.pow(2, 53),1,-1,-Math.pow(2, 53),1};
System.out.println(DoubleStream.of(t).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
t=DoubleStream.of(t).boxed()
                    .sorted((a,b)->(int)(Math.log(Math.abs(a))-Math.log(Math.abs(b))))
                    .mapToDouble(d->d)
                    .toArray();
System.out.println(DoubleStream.of(t).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

will print an okay order

> ```
> [9.007199254740992E15, 1.0, -1.0, -9.007199254740992E15, 1.0]
> [1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 9.007199254740992E15, -9.007199254740992E15]
> ```

---

So it's nice, but you can actually break it with little effort (the first few lines show that 2^53 really is the "integer limit" for `double`, and also "reminds" us of the actual value, then the sum with a single +1 ends up being less than 2^53):

```
double d=Math.pow(2, 53);
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(d).longValue());
d++;
d++;
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(d).longValue());
d+=2;
System.out.println(Double.valueOf(d).longValue());
double array[]= {Math.pow(2, 53),1,1,1,1};
for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
    var copy=Arrays.copyOf(array, i+1);
    d=DoubleStream.of(copy).sum();
    System.out.println(i+": "+Double.valueOf(d).longValue());
}
```

produces

> ```
> 9007199254740992
> 9007199254740992      <-- 9007199254740992+1+1
> 9007199254740994      <-- 9007199254740992+2
> 0: 9007199254740992
> 1: 9007199254740991   <-- that would be 9007199254740992+1 with Kahan
> 2: 9007199254740994 
> 3: 9007199254740996   <-- "rounding" upwards, just like with (float)16777219 earlier
> 4: 9007199254740996
> ```

TL;DR: you don't need your own Kahan implementation, but use computers with care in general.